# NetworkStream and execution of Commands in C# Sockets

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, network-programming

Using `NetworkStream` I am trying to pass some commands into a Machine with proper `/r/n` in case of new line and `/t` in case if tab key. The purpose of passing commands is to configure a 6 digit code into the machine. The main problem that I am facing is that I can't get the access of the machine frequently, neither can I debug my application. For this I am writing messages into text file after the successful execution of each command and trying to catch the error/exception in case occured into text file. After the execution of the program I am not able to get that code into the machine and neither getting any type of error/exception in text file.

One thing that I noticed in my code is that I have not closed  `NetworkStream.close();`. Is this the issue or something different? Also I am passing a command to the machine and I am not trying to get any type of response from the machine. Is it okay to I should try to get response from machine also.

Also while executing above commands in TELNET I am able to configure the authcode.

Here is my sample code:

```
try
{
    using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
    {
        byte[] terminal = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(port2 + "\r\n");
        stream.Write(terminal, 0, terminal.Length);

        Thread.Sleep(5000);

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Terminal Value Entered !");
        }
        byte[] aChServ = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ch + "\r\n");
            stream.Write(aChServ, 0, aChServ.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("New Authcode Request !");
            }


            byte[] aSpace = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("      " + "\t" + " ");
            stream.Write(aSpace, 0, aSpace.Length);

            Thread.Sleep(5000);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(textfileSaveLocation, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine("Authcode Configured !");
            }
        }
```

Code Opening Connection..

```
            try
            {

                client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), intport));

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log the error here.
                client.Close();

                continue;
            }
```

And Values..

```
port2=4410
string ch = "change authorization-code 999999";
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that with telnet you can communicate with the machine. In your socket session do you follow the telnet protocol specifications? read [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc854.txt).

Keep in mind that telnet `"\n\r"` is not what you think it is. In a telnet session you do not send new lines (\n or #10 or Ctrl+J) characters. All you can do is send `carriage return` which may be converted to `line feed` by the emulator.

It's difficult to give you a straight answer, but one thing I can recommend is that you save the session of your telnet emulation and analyzed it, there is a lot of software out there that can show you the packets you send and receive thru the network. If it works with an emulator then it should work with a socket session, but you `must obey` the rules.

Comment: I tried to execute the whole operation by using TELNET command in cmd.exe and its working fine.Same way i tried to follow in socket programming, for example if i pressed ENTER key in the cmd.exe then here in socket program i entered "/r/n" and if TAB key i used "/t" .Then why is it nor happening?

Comment: @Siddhu Can you edit your question and post the code where you open the socket connection? Also the values of port2 and ch variables?